# How to copy files and folders from one network share to another

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file in one network shared folder \\170.23.23.34 and I want  to copy the file to another share \\170.23.23.36.

What should be the batch script for the same.

Answer (score 1):

[Map the network drives](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-shortcut-map-network-drive) in Windows to a specific letter. Once you do that, you can use `xcopy` to copy the necessary files.

e.g.
`XCOPY /E Y:/source-folder/ Z:/destination-folder`

where \\170.23.23.34 would be assigned to Y: and \\170.23.23.36 would be assigned to Z:.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows Vista or later, [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) is better than XCOPY.  You don't need to bother with drive mappings, since it handles UNC paths just fine.  The syntax would be:

```
Robocopy \\170.23.23.34\Share \\170.23.23.36\Share
```

Check the link for various switch options.  For example, you might want to use

```
Robocopy \\170.23.23.34\Share \\170.23.23.36\Share /copy:DATSO
```

to retain ACL and owner information.  Also, Robocopy is tolerant of interupts.  That is, it can pick up where it left off if it gets stopped for some reason.  If you want to maintain a duplicate copy over time, the /mir switch is useful.  It deletes files in the target directory if they no longer exist in the source.